# maven-metadata.xml not beeing downloaded fore release versions

Tags: eclipse, maven, artifactory, tibco

I have the following problem.

In our application POM we have the usual dependency import:

```
<dependency>
      <groupId>com.bwce.fw</groupId>
      <artifactId>CommonFramework</artifactId>
      <version>1.0.0</version>
      <scope>runtime</scope>
    </dependency>
```

When we try to open the application in Eclipse, usually eclipse (maven) downloads the dependencies from our artifactory, stores them in the local `.m2` folder and then eclipse puts the dependency into the workspace.

Everything works fine if we are dealing with SNAPSHOT versions of our custom lib, I see the jars appearing in the `m2` folder and also the `maven-metadata.xml` .

On the other hand when a lib is in a released version the jars are downloaded into the `m2`, but no `maven-metadata.xml` is downloaded, and because of that eclipse doesn't import the jar into the workspace.

If I copy the `maven-metadata.xml` that is in artifactory and put it on `C:\Users\XXX\.m2\repository\com\bwce\fw\CommonFramework`, next to the folder 1.0.0, it works and eclipse imports the dependency into the workspace.

Just as context, we are working with mavenized TIBCO BWCE applications, but I don't think that this is directly related to this.

Thank you in advance.